# If God know everything prior to its happen then was God unable to know that Adam and Eve will sin? If He knew then why did He kept that there?

Tags: genesis, adam-and-eve, fall-of-man, omniscience

God knows everything. He must have known that Adam and Eve will sin. So why did He knowing that they will sin made that situation to happen?

Comment: This is a very frequent question on the site. Some denominations teach that indeed God did know that Adam and Eve would sin.   You should scope the question to a particular denomination since the answers will vary from one to another.

Comment: This question, although interesting, calls for knowing the mind of God; which none can know. As such it not is not a good fit for this site.

Comment: Before the foundation of the world, God determined, in counsel, that provision would be made for the inevitable failure of the created creature. Thanks be to God.